# Variable selection using VSURF package in r

Tags: r

Good morning,

I am trying to select significant variables for prediction purposes based on Robin et al approach (2010) using library (VSURF) in r. The results that i found that from 72 features: 24 variables are oobove the threshold
4 variables selected for interpretation and 3 variables selected for prediction.

Is it logic to find 3 significant variables for prediction?

I am confused i need help and thank you

Comment: This is probably a good question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/. I'm not familiar with VSURF, but finding only 3 variables selected for prediction must mean that only 3 / 72 of the features in your dataset add enough information to reduce error under cross validated predictions.

Comment: Thanks for your answerSo the question should i use these 3 variables selected in the preprocessing stage to build a classification model ?

Comment: It depends on what you would like your classification model to do. If your goal is simplicity, you might want to just use those 3 from the VSURF output.

Comment: I am going to develop a prediction model of coronary risk events and i have 72 clinical factors(features) . its bizarre to find just 3 of them significant in prediction. i don't know i f i have to consider just this three variables for classification will be my model efficient ?

Comment: if you are seeking a classification model with the lowest prediction error, you might need to incorporate a majority of the 72 features in your data, and variable selection might not be very important. if you're looking for a model that is simple and possibly explainable, you might want to go with the 3 or 4 features selected from the VSURF package. I would also suggest looking at the `glmnet` package for variable selection, because it can "shrink away" features that don't matter for prediction, giving you a simpler regression model

Comment: thanks for ur answer